# how to get Javascript variable value using <c:url>tag

Tags: javascript, spring, jstl

i am using jstl and Jquery
 - jQuery
**MyCode**

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var tds = $(tr).find("td:not('.editor_edit')").get();
jobid=($(tds[0]).text());
alert("ans "+jobid);
window.location.href ='<c:url value="/coverFileDesign?jobId=${jobid}"/>';
```

How to get Javascript variable value in tab to pass value to controller class

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html), you can create the tag with XML markup previously, and then access it with a variable. Example:

**HTML**

```
<c:url var="myUrl" value="/coverFileDesign" >
    <c:param name="jobId" value="${jobId}" />
</c:url>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var tds = $(tr).find("td:not('.editor_edit')").get();
jobid=($(tds[0]).text());
alert("ans "+jobid);
window.location.href ="${myUrl}";
```

------------------------ Edit ------------------------

To send a value through JavaScript, you can just add the value to the string. Example:

**JavaScript**

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var tds = $(tr).find("td:not('.editor_edit')").get();
jobid=($(tds[0]).text());
alert("ans "+jobid);
window.location.href = '<c:url value="/coverFileDesign" />?jobId='+jobid;
```

Comment: I am using DataTable Code

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with your question. Can you explain it please?

Comment: i got jobid in alert box and then how to pass that jobid into location.href = '/coverFileDesign?jobId=' + jobid; to controller class using spring mvc